# Concatenate files together that have similar names

Tags: string, bash, file

I have a number of files that look something like this:

```
418_S32_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz
418_S32_L003_R2_001.fastq.gz
418_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
418_S1_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
419_S32_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz
419_S32_L003_R2_001.fastq.gz
419_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
419_S1_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

The first number is different for each set of four files.
Samples that start with the same number should be combined together if they have the same value for `*R1*` or `*R2*`.

So, these two samples should be concatenated:

```
418_S32_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz
418_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

And these two should be concatenated:

```
419_S32_L003_R2_001.fastq.gz
419_S1_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

And this should be repeated for all files within the directory.

Is there a good way to do this in bash other than manually concatenating like this:

```
cat 418_S32_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz 418_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz > 418_R1.fastq.gz
```

Comment: Generate a list of the filenames in question. `sort` this list, by defining `_` as field separator, by the first and forth fields. If you don't have files with odd names (i.e. names with embedded newlines) in your directory, this is `sorted=( $(ls *.fastq.gz|sort .....) )` This gives you a new, ordered list, where the names of the files to be catenated, are adjecent to each other. Now process the list sequentially, opening a new output file whenever the "key values" (418, R1) change. Have a look at the bash man page for regular expressions on how to extract these key values from a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read each file and append it to the target file which you can get from the file name.

```
    for file in *.fastq.gz;
    do
        IFS='_' read -a array <<< $file;
        name="${array[0]}_${array[3]}.fastq.gz";
        cat $file >> $name;
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 0
for i in *
do
for j in *
do 
if [ $(echo $j |cut -d _ -f 1) = $(echo $i |cut -d _ -f 1) ]
then 
cat $i $j > $a
a = a + 1
fi
done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel --dry-run -N4 --plus cat {1} {4} \> {1%_.*}_R1.{1+..} ::: *R[12]*
```

This will print out the intended `cat` commands, check the results and if OK remove the `--dry-run` option.